# Netty 4.0 IdleStateHandler not working correctly

Tags: java, netty

EDIT: Everything works correctly. The problem was entirely on another side. This can be used as a working example.

I'm trying to implement an IdleStateHandler with Netty 4.0.9 in my server.
The problem that I'm getting is that it doesn't fire the IdleStateEvent.

To test I'm simply making the client "crash" like I did with OIO (and everything worked as intended in that case).

I'm sure I have no blocking anywhere, everything works fine (including the normal closing connection request from the client).

Here it is my code...
Pipeline

```
public PipelineInitializer(){
    super();
}

@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    // Idle Handlers
    ch.pipeline().addLast("IdleChecker", new IdleStateHandler(15,0,0));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("IdleDisconnecter", new IdleDisconnecter());

    // Decoding Handlers
    ch.pipeline().addLast("Framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("Decoder", STR_DECODER);

    // Encoding Handlers
    ch.pipeline().addLast("Encoder", STR_ENCODER);

    // Processing Handlers (if Idle Event, disconnects)
    ch.pipeline().addLast("ServiceSelector", new ServiceSelector());
}
```

and the Handler which is supposed to handle the IdleEvent:

```
public class IdleDisconnecter extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

public IdleDisconnecter(){
    super();
}

@Override
public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Event Fired"); // Doesn't trigger
    if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
        System.out.println("Event is IdleStateEvent"); // Doesn't trigger
        if (((IdleStateEvent) evt).state() == IdleState.READER_IDLE) {
            System.out.println("Event is a Reader one"); // Doesn't trigger
            throw new Exception(); //I want this to be catch by the last handler in the pipeline
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggest? Probably I've made some stupid error that I refuse to see, I don't know, but I'm completely out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: This should work... Can you submit a test-case which shows the problem on the netty bug tracker ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and indeed it works correctly, the problem is on the client side. I'll leave the question as a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add
*`ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);`*
in your other handler.
More info you can see [Netty Handler not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056557/netty-handler-not-called).